# Excel, formulae to find the latest modified row from a set of duplicated records

Tags: excel

I have a excel that contains a bunch of duplicate rows of information. Each set of duplicate records are grouped by `groupId` and have a `Modified Date` for each of them. The image below shows the table in which I would like to add "Latest" in the `Latest Record` column.

What formulae would I need. I have tried with MATCH and INDEX but cant quite get the correct formulae to perform the task needed.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming latest column is A, put the following formula in A2:

```
IF(C2 <> C3, "Latest", "")
```

Then copy this formula within column A. This solution assumes the data is sorted by groupid, modified.

Comment: I still need the other rows as they may contain information the latest record doesn't have. The excel are across thousands of rows, so manually will take time. I would just like to highlight that these rows are the latest modified.

Comment: @Ross See if this will do.